# Python - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list that looks as follows:

```
[array(46), array(0.09), array(5.3), array(4), array(23), array(33), array([0, 1])]
```

When I try to save it however, as follows:

```
np.save('model.npy', data)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What is causing the error? Is it the `array([0, 1]`? Or something to do on how to format the list.

Thanks.

Comment: Try checking what `np.save('model.npy', [array([0, 1])])` does if you suspect that's the issue.

Comment: `np.save` is designed to save a *single* array to a file.  Your list contains six scalar arrays and one one-dimensional array with length 2.  Maybe you could try [`np.savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html).

Comment: If you're trying to save arbitrary data, maybe just use `pickle.dump`?

Comment: A list of 6 zero-dimensional arrays and 1 one-dimensional array is not a data structure likely to come up in normal NumPy usage. The fact that you even have this thing suggests that there may be bigger problems with your code.

Answer (score 1):

`np.save` saves arrays, not lists.  So it has to first convert your list to an array.  But when I do that:

```
In [192]: array=np.array
In [193]: data = np.array([array(797.41993), array(0.5880978458210907), array(0.606072
     ...: 7759272153), array(0.590397955349836), array(0.5688937568615196), array(0.56
     ...: 70561030951616), array([0, 1])])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-390218c41b83> in <module>()
----> 1 data = np.array([array(797.41993), array(0.5880978458210907), array(0.6060727759272153), array(0.590397955349836), array(0.5688937568615196), array(0.5670561030951616), array([0, 1])])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

All your sub arrays have single items, but the last has 2.  If I remove that, it can create an array.

```
In [194]: data = np.array([array(797.41993), array(0.5880978458210907), array(0.606072
     ...: 7759272153), array(0.590397955349836), array(0.5688937568615196), array(0.56
     ...: 70561030951616)])
In [195]: data
Out[195]: 
array([  7.97419930e+02,   5.88097846e-01,   6.06072776e-01,
         5.90397955e-01,   5.68893757e-01,   5.67056103e-01])
```

`np.array(...)` tries to create as high a dimensional array as it can.  If the elements vary in size it can't do that.  In some cases it will create a object dtype array.  But in this it raised an error.

---

With the 1d item first it creates the object dtype:

```
In [196]: data = np.array([array([0, 1]), array(797.41993), array(0.5880978458210907),
     ...:  array(0.6060727759272153), array(0.590397955349836), array(0.56889375686151
     ...: 96), array(0.5670561030951616)])
In [197]: data
Out[197]: 
array([array([0, 1]), array(797.41993), array(0.5880978458210907),
       array(0.6060727759272153), array(0.590397955349836),
       array(0.5688937568615196), array(0.5670561030951616)], dtype=object)
```

Or with `hstack` as @wim suggests:

```
In [198]: data = np.hstack([array(797.41993), array(0.5880978458210907), array(0.60607
     ...: 27759272153), array(0.590397955349836), array(0.5688937568615196), array(0.5
     ...: 670561030951616), array([0, 1])])
In [199]: data
Out[199]: 
array([  7.97419930e+02,   5.88097846e-01,   6.06072776e-01,
         5.90397955e-01,   5.68893757e-01,   5.67056103e-01,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Best explanation of this error I can find is [here](https://metaphor.ethz.ch/fsdb/sam/PythonTutorial/frequent_errors.html_)

> The error `setting an array element with a sequence` happens if we try to write something into a single place (`array` cell, `matrix` entry) of an `array` and this something is **not a scalar value.**

This happens

- when you try to set a single value in an array to some sort of container object (array, tuple, list, etc)
- when you try to process "ragged" datatypes (i.e. constructs that are not n-d rectangular) using methods designed to be used only on arrays (which is pretty much anything in `numpy`)

In this case, `np.save` only works on single arrays, so it starts with applying `asanyarray()` on your input.  This sees a list of seven "things" of which the first is a `float`, and tries to fit them into a `arr.shape = (7,), arr.dtype = float` array.  When it gets to the last element, it tries to set `arr[6] = array([0, 1])` and throws the error.